# Design approach?

Tags: odata, strategy-pattern

I'm currently working on a OData Service(SAP Gateway), wherein the entity types are generated during the runtime. I know, that this wouldn't be as per the OData best practices, where the entity types should be static and is part of the design phase.

Questions:
1. With the request for metadata, all the entity types are generated in a method called DEFINE(provided by SAP Gateway framework). I'd like to separate the generation of each entity type, as the information required for the generation is different for each entity type. Later on, new entity types will be added, which would have a further set of instructions for the generation. 
Is the Strategy pattern best for this? With this, the generation of different entity types are separated. If Strategy, then, should the Factory method return all the concrete strategies at once and let the context loop through all the strategies to generate the entity types?

Or is there any other design approach for this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How could you define specialized generation strategies per type in advance if the types are generated at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The entity types are defined in method DEFINE. The definition is nothing but creation of entity type based on a defined data structure. The code required to create entity types varies for each entity type. With runtime, I mean, the code written as the definition of entity type, is executed to form an entity type during the request for metada.